# How To Scrape Table From Restricted Website

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape data from a particular site. Later, I realized that the site does not allow data scraping. After a number of google searches, I was able to bypass the rule. However, I could not obtain the desired result from the page. My goal is to get the first four pages of the table into a csv file. I was able to get the headers of the table(from the code attached), but not the table data. I want to be guided on how to achieve my goal.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2023/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/100/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"

HEADERS = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    }

data = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all("th", attrs={"class": ["stats","name","rank"]})

header = []
for i in table:
  header.append(i.text.strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
```

Comment: Looks like the data is loaded dynamically, so you will need something like `selenium`. However, the same info is also available on other sites. E.g. I've found the table for *ranking* also on https://edudaily24.com/en/world-university-rankings-2023/. Now, you are in luck there, because for this particular site, you can just use [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). Try `df = pd.read_html('https://edudaily24.com/en/world-university-rankings-2023/')[-1]` et voilà: the entire table all the way through to the last page from timeshighereducation.com.

Comment: You will want to split the entries in column `NameCountry/Region`, e.g. apply `df.iloc[:,1].str.split(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', n=1)` and get `['University of Oxford', 'United Kingdom']` instead of `'University of OxfordUnited Kingdom'`.

Answer (score 0):

This site allows you to get data in `json` format, so it will be enough to use the `requests` library to get it. Here is one possible solution:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/world_university_rankings_2023_0__83be12210294c582db8740ee29673120.json"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}

# get a list of universities
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()['data']
# list of unused keys
key_list = [
    "scores_citations", "scores_citations_rank", "cta_button", "apply_link", "url",
    "scores_industry_income", "scores_industry_income_rank", "subjects_offered",
    "aliases", "rank_order", "scores_overall", "scores_overall_rank", "scores_teaching",
    "closed", "unaccredited", "disabled", "record_type", "scores_teaching_rank",
    "scores_research", "scores_research_rank", "scores_international_outlook", 
    "scores_international_outlook_rank", "member_level", "nid"
    ]
# old and new column names
columns = {
    "rank": "Rank", "name": "Name", "location": "Country", 
    "stats_number_students": "No. of FTE Students", 
    "stats_student_staff_ratio": "No. of students per staff", 
    "stats_pc_intl_students": "International Students", "stats_female_male_ratio": "Female:Male Ratio"
    }

tdf = []
# take the first 400 universities
for university in data[:400]:
    # remove unused keys
    for key in key_list :
        university.pop(key, None)
    # create DataFrame and change its orientation
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(university.items())).set_index(0).T
    tdf.append(df)
# reset index and rename columns
df = pd.concat(tdf).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns=columns)
# save to csv
df.to_csv("university_rankings_2023.csv")
```

Output DataFrame:

```
0       Rank                                   Name         Country No. of FTE Students No. of students per staff International Students Female:Male Ratio
0          1                   University of Oxford  United Kingdom              20,967                      10.6                    42%           48 : 52
1          2                     Harvard University   United States              21,887                       9.6                    25%           50 : 50
2         =3                University of Cambridge  United Kingdom              20,185                      11.3                    39%           47 : 53
3         =3                    Stanford University   United States              16,164                       7.1                    24%           46 : 54
4          5  Massachusetts Institute of Technology   United States              11,415                       8.2                    33%           40 : 60
..       ...                                    ...             ...                 ...                       ...                    ...               ...
395  351–400                    University of Vaasa         Finland               3,873                      20.0                     4%           53 : 47
396  351–400                      Verona University           Italy              18,621                      23.8                     4%           64 : 36
397  351–400                 Wake Forest University   United States               8,122                       4.0                    10%           54 : 46
398  351–400            Washington State University   United States              29,463                      19.5                     7%           54 : 46
399  351–400             Wroclaw Medical University          Poland               6,769                       9.4                    14%           71 : 29
```

And `university_rankings_2023.csv`

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize the site provides the data in `json`. Have a look at [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). I.e. given your dict `columns`, you can just write: `df = pd.json_normalize(data).loc[:399, columns.keys()].rename(columns=columns)`. No need for the loop and concatenation.

Comment: Where did you find the link to the json file?

Comment: @AkpakliEdudzi you can find it on the "Network" tab in DevTools by setting the filter for "Fetch/XHR" requests

Comment: Just curious. How did you know it was there